# Do I need to configure the binding at both client and server?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am using NetNamedPipeBding to communicate with a service in local machine. I understand I need to define the configuration settings for client like maxstringcontentlength, sendtimeout, maxbyteperread etc.

Do I need to define the same things at server side as well? What is the relationship between these two? If the client doesn't have configuration settings while connecting to it, will it use its default binding settings? Are they totally independent?

For ex: I defined the below settings for client

```
    <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
               openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
               transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
               hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
               maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None">
                <!--<transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />-->
              </security>
            </binding>
          </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

And I also defined at server side similar settings:

```
  <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Namespace.Service" />
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
           transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
           hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
           maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <!--<transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>                 
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some settings are relevant on both ends and some are relevant only on the server while some on client. Generally most settings should have same value and yes you need to configure the binding at both ends. One will not use the settings of other after connection is established.

Comment: Thanks Hasan. I would like to understand in-depth about these options especially ones which are relevant at both ends. For ex: maxstringcontentlength, maxarraylenghth will be applied on both ends. If yes, which one will get preference etc...